# Can't connect to mysql server (LAMP) in google cloud

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, lamp

I installed `LAMP` on a VM instance on Google cloud but when i try to access **mysql** database remotely from my linux terminal using

```
$ mysql -u username -h ipaddress -p
```

after entering password nothing happens (no error). I tried accessing it locally via ssh it works.

Is there any other setting on cloud platform. I need to change before accessing database from a remote pc. Followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access) tutorial but it just stops after entering password.

Tried commenting out bind address but didn't work. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, are you using the `mysql` command on your remote machine or through SSH?

Normally, you should never allow external access to remote MySQL for security reasons, especially if the only app accessing the data is local. (however, it's unclear if that is the reason why you can't connect)

This is how you should connect:

1. Connect to your remote VM using SSH (ex: `ssh user@ipaddress`)
2. THEN, connect to your MySQL instance.

When connecting using a DB editor, some editors allow MySQL connections through SSH. Sequel Pro for Mac does this very well.